# How do I extract repeated values in a dataframe basaed on information from another column?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a data set that looks like this:

[image: samples stacked based on Gene Function]

a <- I want to filter the rows with the same GeneFunction that has the highest Shared_NDC_Coverage.
b <-  In addition, I would also like to keep rows that are higher than the 10% of the highest Shared_NDC_Coverage (the information we get at a) for that subset of the group that we filtered for each TreatmentGeneFunction.

I am new to R, and trying to self teach myself the some of the basics. I appreciate any kind of help. Thank you!

So far I have tried the following codes but they are not really working;

```
sample <- read.csv("Ksg_3Q_vs_NDCsharedSupplemented_T60_Top_Newannot.csv")
sample <- arrange(sample, TreatmentGeneFuncion)

for(a in 1:nrow(sample)){
  if(sample$TreatmentGene[a] == sample$NDCGene[a]){
    sample[a] <- which.max(sample$Shared_NDC_Coverage[a])
  }
}

sample2<- distinct(sample, TreatmentGeneFuncion, .keep_all = TRUE) #This only returns the first row of the repeated values
```

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 0):

Guesses:

```r
a <- subset(sample, GeneFunction == GeneFunction[which.max(Shared_NDC_Coverage)])

b <- subset(sample, Shared_NDC_Coverage >= 0.1 * max(a$Shared_NDC_Coverage))
```